# Coloring scatterplot in R based on fold enrichment

Tags: r

I'm very new to R and have tried to search around for an answer to my question, but couldn't find quite what I was looking for (or I just couldn't figure out the right keywords to include!). I think this is a fairly common task in R though, I am just very new.

I have a x vs y scatterplot and I want to color those points for which there is at least a 2-fold enrichment, ie where x/y>=2 . Since my values are expressed as log2 values, the the transformed value needs to be x/y>=4.

I currently have the scatterplot plotted with

```
plot(log2(counts[,40], log2(counts[,41))
```

where counts is a .csv imported files and 40 & 41 are my columns of interested.

I've also created a column for fold change using

```
counts$fold<-counts[,41]/counts[,40]
```

I don't know how to incorporate these two pieces of information... Ultimately I want a graph that looks something like the example here: http://s17.postimg.org/s3k1w8r7j/error_messsage_1.png
 where those points that are at least two-fold enriched will colored in blue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: For future reference, you're more likely to get help that's tailored directly to your problem if you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), especially a sample of your data, the code you've tried so far, and the results you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
# Fake data
dat = data.frame(x=runif(100,0,50), y = rnorm(100, 10, 2))

plot(dat$x, dat$y, col=ifelse(dat$x/dat$y > 4, "blue", "red"), pch=16)
```

The `ifelse` statement creates a vector of "blue" and "red" (or whatever colors you want) based on the values of `dat$x/dat$y` and `plot` uses that to color the points.

[This might be helpful](http://research.stowers-institute.org/efg/Report/UsingColorInR.pdf) if you've never worked with colors in `R`.

[image]

Another option is to use `ggplot2` instead of base graphics. Here's an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x,y, colour=cut(x/y, breaks=c(-1000,4,1000), 
                                labels=c("<=4",">4")))) + 
  geom_point(size=5) + 
  labs(colour="x/y")
```

[image]